# Replace a value in a dataframe with a value from another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a replacing problem in python. I'm trying to replace all the integer value in the column `ORIGIN_AIRPORT` from `df_2` with the `IATA` column from `df_1`. The key-columns are `ORIGIN_AIRPOR`T from `df_2` and `ID` from `df_1`.

`df_2` has about `5.800.000` datasets and `df_1` about `6.400`.

I think there is an easy way to do it, but I don't know how.

`df_1`:

```
    ID      IATA
0   10001   01A
1   10003   03A
2   10004   04A
3   10005   05A
4   10006   06A
.
.
.
```

`df_2`:

```
        YEAR    MONTH   DAY DAY_OF_WEEK AIRLINE FLIGHT_NUMBER   TAIL_NUMBER ORIGIN_AIRPORT  DESTINATION_AIRPORT 
4385712 2015    10      1   4           AA      1230            N3DBAA      SEA             ANC 
4385713 2015    10      1   4           DL      1805            N696DL      10001           13487   
4385714 2015    10      1   4           NK      612             N602NK      10006           13487   
.
.
.
```

At the end the df shoul look like df_3.

`df_3`:

```
        YEAR    MONTH   DAY DAY_OF_WEEK AIRLINE FLIGHT_NUMBER   TAIL_NUMBER ORIGIN_AIRPORT  DESTINATION_AIRPORT 
4385712 2015    10      1   4           AA      1230            N3DBAA      SEA             ANC 
4385713 2015    10      1   4           DL      1805            N696DL      01A             13487   
4385714 2015    10      1   4           NK      612             N602NK      06A             13487   
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to write the simplest solution for this :

**Step 1: Convert both columns from df_1 into a dictionary by using the following code:**

```
d = dict(zip(df_1.ID,df_1.IATA))
```

**Step 2: Now we just need to map this dictionary and df_2:**

```
df_2.ORIGIN_AIRPORT= df_1.ID.map(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a left join of `df_1` and `df_2`.

Given the moderate size of `df1`, you can just create a mapping rule:

```
mapping = {}
for row in df_1.iterrows():
    mapping[row[0]] = row[1]
```

And create a new column:

```
df2['AIRPORT_PROCESSED'] = df2['ORIGIN_AIRPORT'].apply(lambda x: mapping.get(x, x))
```

The last function will replace `ORIGIN_AIRPORT` value for the value from mapping if `x` is in `mapping`.