# Change the value from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python. I'm want to change all the values in the column 'Starting' from df_2 with the 'Station' column from df_1. I did it by using for loop . But How can I perform this task in simplest way?

df_1:

```
  ID     Station
0   1      Satose
1   2      Forlango
2   3      poterio
.
.
```

df_2:

```
 Rail_Number  Starting      Ending 
     AABDD       3           44433 
     DLRAKA      1           45232
     MiGOMu      2           18756   
      .
      .
```

Comment: @Torxed I am using pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have answered a similar question here :

[Replace a value in a dataframe with a value from another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61175252/replace-a-value-in-a-dataframe-with-a-value-from-another-dataframe/61179874#61179874)

**Step 1: Convert both columns from df_1 into a dictionary by using the following code:**

```
d = dict(zip(df_1.ID,df_1.Station))
```

**Step 2: Now we just need to map this dictionary and df_2:**

```
df_2.Starting = df_1.ID.map(d)
```